Anime series that involves a "battle" between two fast food chains in Japan?
I'm looking for an anime series that's set in modern-day Japan (Tokyo, I think). The main character, a male with white/blonde hair, gets a job at a fast food burger restaurant (McDonald's, basically). Eventually a KFC knock-off opens across the street and forces the burger place to fight for customers with various marketing strategies. Eventually the burger place wins their customers back, and either a balance is struck between the two or the chicken place closes.
I think there's a supernatural element where the protagonist was cast into the human world as a punishment and that's why he has to get a job, but I have no clue what sort of background he would have if that's correct. He may have just been a rich kid kicked out of his family. 
If I remember correctly, he moves into a small 2-room apartment with a black-haired friend. And then his younger brother moves in later.
Probably watched it on Netflix some time after 2010.

The closest anime that fits this description is The Devil Is a Part-Timer!, or Hataraku Maou-sama:

The Demon Lord Satan and one of his generals, Alciel, escape the world of Ente Isla through a gate to modern Tokyo, Japan after being confronted by the Hero Emilia and her companions. However, due to the lack of magic in the modern contemporary world, both Satan and Alciel change into forms representing what they would look like if they were human. In order to survive, Satan takes a part-time job in a fast food restaurant named MgRonald while Alciel serves as his houseman. One day, Satan, who now goes by Sadao Maō, meets a girl who is actually the Hero Emilia, who now goes by Emi Yusa. The story then unfolds and explores the personalities of each of the characters and their moral values. More characters show up from Ente Isla and they too face the new world dilemmas, often comically.

Some notes: The friend (general) has light hair, it's the main character who has dark hair, and the guy who moves in next is not his younger brother but a fallen angel. The competition between not-McDonald's and not-KFC is mostly as you described, however.
